# mongodb server connection error

Tags: mongodb

```
waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/? 
compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-03T16:17:52.233+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: 
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-03T16:17:52.271+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-03T16:17:52.271+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your mongo service is running or not. Try to enable the the mongo by using the command `sudo systemctl enable mongod` .

After that restart the mongo service by using the command.

`sudo service mongod restart`

Comment: waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ sudo systemctl restart mongodb.service.
Failed to restart mongodb.service..service: Unit mongodb.service..service not found.

Comment: waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ sudo systemctl restart mongodb.service.
Failed to restart mongodb.service..service: Unit mongodb.service..service not found.

Comment: it looks like mongodb-server is not installed.

Comment: @Waseem-wassu I have updated the answer please check.